# Public array variable of variable size

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, global-variables

I'd like to have a global array variable in Excel VBA whose array size depends on a second global variable.

I'm trying something like this..

```
Public int1 As Integer

Sub foo()
    int1 =  '##read from ini file
    Public varArray(1 To int1) As Variant
    For i = 1 To int1
        varArray(i)= '##read from ini file
    Next i
    Call SomeProcedure '##in another module where varArray is used
End Sub
```

Now obviously this doesn't work since global formulas must be declared outside the sub, and it seems that also Arrays need a constant when I give them a range. Is there any way I can do it by just declaring

```
Public varArray() As Integer
```

and then give it a number of elements later? It doesn't seem to let me do that, and nothing else I tried...

Comment: You can always pass the array to the next sub.

Comment: But you would simply redim the array inside the sub foo() `ReDim varArray(1 To int1) As Variant`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the array has to be declared outside the sub to be global.

To resize the array, use the `ReDim` command inside of another function, after you determine how big the array needs to be.

```
Dim varArray() As Variant

Public Sub Foo()
    'Determine size of array
    'For example, let's say you determine you need 15 elements
    ArraySize = 15 'Your variable here, instead of 15

    ReDim varArray(1 To ArraySize)

    'Debug Print statement to confirm array dimensions
    Debug.Print LBound(varArray) & " - " & UBound(varArray)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much, just what I was looking for.